# Azure table storage from Python function consistently failing when looking up for missing entity

Tags: python-3.x, azure-functions, azure-table-storage

I have the following setup:

1. Azure function in Python 3.6 is processing some entities utilizing
   the TableService class from the Python Table API (new one for
   CosmosDB) to check whether the currently processed entity is already
   in a storage table. This is done by invoking
   TableService.get_entity.
2. get_entity method throws exception each
   time it does not find an entity with the given rowid (same as the
   entity id) and partition key.
3. If no entity with this id is found then i call insert_entity to add it to the table.

With this i am trying to implement processing only of entities that haven't been processed before (not logged in the table).
I observe however consistent behaviour of the function simply freezing after exactly 10 exceptions, where it halts execution on the 10th invocation and does not continue processing for another minute or 2!

I even changed the implementation of instead doing a lookup first to simply call insert_entity and let it fail when a duplicate row key is added. Surprisingly enough the behaviour there is exactly the same - on the 10th duplicate invocation the execution freezes and continues after a while.

What is the cause of such behaviour? Is this some sort of protection mechanism on the storage account that kicks in? Or is it something to do with the Python client? To me it looks very much something by design. 
I wasnt able to find any documentation or settings page on the portal for influencing such behaviour.

I am wondering of it is possible to implement such logic with using table storage? I don't seem to find it justifiable to spin up a SQL Azure db or Cosmos DB instance for such trivial functionality of checking whether an entity does not exist in a table.

Thanks